# How to utilize saved Chrome password to implement an auto-login script, so that I don't have to put plain-text password in the script?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, automation, selenium-chromedriver, testcafe

The passwords are in my default Chrome profile, which is also what I use for regular browsing. In Selenium, I tried the following

```
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=/Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/')
```

But it complains

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

However I need to have a browser with the default `--user-data-dir` open to do my regular browsing. Is there a way to resolve this conflict, e.g. have my manually-opened session and the Selenium-opened session share a `--user-data-dir`? Or have the Selenium-opened session attach to my manually-opened session?

If it is not possible, one compromise I could make is to let Selenium use a different `--user-data-dir`. As a one time work, I can first let Chrome save the passwords for the few websites that I care about. However, it seems that when I use a different `--user-data-dir`, the opened browser session no longer enables password storing.

I also tried the TestCafe tool, but it also seems to open a non-default profile.

Answer (score 3):

TestCafe allows you to use the current Chrome profile for testing purposes.
As stated in the documentation:

> If you need to start a browser with the current user profile, you can
>   do this by specifying the :userProfile flag after the browser alias.

Please refer to the following article to get details: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/browsers/user-profiles.html

Or you can use the `--user-data-dir` flag to specify a custom user profile directory: `testcafe "chrome --user-data-dir=<path>" test.js`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems interesting. However it seems that testcafe prepends my target URL with <MY_IP>:<PORT>/<SOME RANDOM STRING>/. Therefore Chrome doesn't auto-populate the username/password fields because it doesn't match the stored URL. Is there any workaround for this? Even if I can manually re-enter my username/password for sites I care about with this prefix, this prefix does change everytime, so that's also infeasible. I suppose if there's a way to fix this prefix, it might work?

Comment: You can define the hostname and port for testing by using the [--hostname](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--hostname-name) and [--ports](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--ports-port1port2) options. However, as you can see, the session id is randomly generated for each test, and it cannot be defined by a static value.